# Custom post type and have_posts() return empty result

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

I'm very confused regarding the have_posts(). It returns an empty result even though I have one post that match the query.

The below code is used in a widget which should display exactly one post, if it exists. I use wordpress 3.3...

```
$singleargs = array('p' => 2040, 'post_type' => 'event', 'post_status' => array('any'), 'posts_per_page' => 1);
$singlequery = new WP_Query( $singleargs );
//print_r($singlequery);
echo "I'm here 1!!<br>";
while ( $singlequery->have_posts() ) :
echo "I'm here 2!!<br>";
$singlequery->the_post();
// output post data...
endwhile;
```

The above code outputs only **"I'm here 1!!"**, nothing else. But if I remove the **while ( $singlequery->have_posts() ) :** and **endwhile;** then I get **"I'm here 1!!"**, **"I'm here 2!!"** and the correct output of the post that was found. So why do **$singlequery->have_posts()** not return true!!???

Comment: what's the 'p'=>2040 doing in the args array?

Comment: +1 with @ptriek... Why the id? It can change if you move between WP installations. And if you still want to use the id, why not use `get_posts` instead?

Comment: The query only has one result because you're specifying the ID inside the arguments, it can't possibly return more than 1 result because IDs are unique, ie. the `p => x` part.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing your query to this?

```
$singleargs = array('post_type' => 'event');
```

It looks like that's what you're going for. The rest of the parameters limits your result to zero or 1.

Also, make sure that the post type name is spelled correctly in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't

```
'post_status' => array('any')
```

Break the query?

I always use

```
'post_status' => null
```

In my code.

By the way, if you know the post id, why just not skip all of the paramaters and just use the 'p'? All of the other parameters are kind of useless then :-)

Hope it helps!